# Add client certificate in DbContextOptionsBuilder in Asp.Net Core using NPGSQL

Tags: asp.net, npgsql

I am trying to add client certificate in the startupfile where i make the connection to my Postgresql server using DbContextOptionsBuilder like below. I also have a connectionstring in another file.

The connection to the server works fine, but when i enable ssl on the server it requires "client certificate" and i cant figure out how to add this in the connection.

My code in startupfile:

```
services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BloggingContext")));
```

My connectionstring:

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Database=myDataBase;Userid=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;Trust Server Certificate=true;SslMode=Require;
```

I found this Doc: "https://www.npgsql.org/doc/security.html#encryption-ssltls"
but having trouble understanding it.

Comment: Check you need to specify "client certificate" connection string parameter and assign the path where the client certificate resides See [this](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html#security-and-encryption)

Comment: It looks like the "client certificate" connection string parameter only takes .crt files is this correct? I am using .pem file format from GCP, is it possible to use this or do i need to convert it to .crt?

Comment: It seems PGSQL supports only `.crt` files. And a side note if you place your `.crt` file in the default directory mentioned [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html#LIBPQ-SSL-CLIENTCERT) you don't need to specify exactly.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `Client Certificate` command-line string, you can also specify [a client certificate callback programmatically](http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/api/Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilder.html#Npgsql_EntityFrameworkCore_PostgreSQL_Infrastructure_NpgsqlDbContextOptionsBuilder_ProvideClientCertificatesCallback_ProvideClientCertificatesCallback_):

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    => optionsBuilder .UseNpgsql("...",  o => o.ProvideClientCertificatesCallback()...);
```

This callback is invoked by Npgsql to populate a standard .NET [`X509CertificateCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificatecollection?view=netframework-4.8) which will be sent to the server.